# Li-Po Battery Management

Tags: battery-charging, low-power, portable

I am creating an open source dive computer (diydivecomputer.com) and have been looking for the simplest way of managing the battery which consists of three functions: 1) managing the charging of the battery, 2) Regulating the output to 3.3v and 3) providing accurate battery level to the processor (gas gauge).

I have not found any solutions that can do all this in one chip or for that matter, less than three (one for each of these functions). Does anyone know of a good, simple solution?  I want the device to worn on the wrist so board space is at a premium.  So far I am looking at Microchip's MCP73831 for charging, the TI's TPS61201 for regulating and TI's BQ27000 for "gas gauge" functionality.  If you can point me in a better direction, I would appreciate it!

FYI: the device will use a 1200mAh Li-Po and use about 40ma while operating.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3553 : integrates (1) and (2). Depending on how regular your current consumption is, gas gauge might not be worth it doing and you can simply estimate it from cell voltage and runtime since last charge.

Answer (score 0):

pjc50 has (1) and (2) covered. For (3), the TI chip looks good but may be difficult for hobbyists to solder without a hot air station or skillet.